# Is Structured Data worth the effort for large websites which rank reasonably well

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, structured-data

My website is a large one (with thousands of pages) and is performing reasonably well in SERPs for several competitive keywords. So far I haven't thought about structured data and rich search results. Are they worth the effort? I know they don't increase rankings but could make the results look appealing. Is there any benefit other than (hopefully) increasing the organic CTR by a small percentage (though not guaranteed)? Or am I missing a point that the CTR is going to multiply 2X or 3X after implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best estimates I've seen is that high-value rich snippets drive **10% to 30% more traffic** from search engines due to increased click through rate (CTR).

Most pages don't have an appropriate high-value rich snippet to implement.   [Google has a pretty small list of rich snippets](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery) that it will show.   The best rich snippets are for pages about things like:

- Products for sale
- Recipes
- User reviews
- Local businesses
- Job postings

Implementing more generic low-value structured data for breadcrumbs, articles, or logos may not even give a measurable bump in CTR.

### Is it worth it?

Implementing structured data is often trivial.   There is often a plugin for it that you can add to your CMS.  Even if you have to program it yourself, the data is usually already in the page and all you have to do is change the markup.   I've implemented far bigger changes in hopes of just a fraction of a percent increase in traffic for a large site.

I tend to worry more about making my site's data programatically available which makes it easier to scrape and misuse.    I recommend only implementing structured data when there is a compelling benefit such as a measurable bump in search engine traffic.

### Sources

I find that marketing firms tend to oversell structured data.   There are a lot of articles touting its benefits.  Very few give numbers and cite studies.  Many make questionable claims and imply that structured data helps rankings even though no evidence of that exists.

I think this is because structured data is very actionable.      Consultants can implement it for you and show that they have done something while hyping its potential.   As such, approach articles about structured data and rich snippets with skepticism.

Here are a few articles that actually cite numbers.   I based my 10% to 30% CTR increase estimate on these articles:

- [How To Get A 30% Increase In CTR With Structured Markup - Search Engine Land](https://searchengineland.com/how-to-get-a-30-increase-in-ctr-with-structured-markup-105830) (2011) -- Examines a dozen online retailers that implemented structured data and saw up to a 30% increase in traffic
- [Study Shows How Rich Media Effects SEO and CTR | Web Marketing Pros](https://www.webmarketingpros.com/study-shows-how-rich-media-effects-seo-and-ctr/) -- Reports on a study by Blue Nile Research that shows ~50% increase  in click through rate from using authorship markup to get photo into the search results.   However this particular rich snippet is no longer available from Google.
- [What are Rich Snippets? A Guide to Website Implementation - SEOquake](https://www.seoquake.com/blog/rich-snippets-guide/) -- Claims that a 5 star recipe review in position 4 outperforms the number 1 result by a factor of fourteen.  Also claims getting a price and "in stock" snippet has a dramatic effect.  However, the analysis is done by comparing SEM Rush data for the ranking URLs instead of getting CTR data from those particular searches.  In one case the article highlights a difference in branded traffic for an unbranded query.
- [How to Optimize for Google's Featured Snippets to Build More Traffic - Moz](https://moz.com/blog/optimize-featured-snippets) (2017) - 20% to 30% more traffic and significantly more revenue from featured snippets.  However featured snippets are not based on structured data or schema.org.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed inputs with actionable references. I will go through the linked resources, cross-compare with my site's prospects and decide on implementing rich snippets.